# The effect of gravitational wave is like tidal forces?

Tags: tidal-forces, gravitational-waves

What would happen if a strong gravitational wave passed through a human body or any other kind of material?

The shape of the human body would change?

Would the human body be distorted apart?

If so, would the person survive?

Comment: The closest thing to your question would be if tidal forces ripped apart someone's body (i.e. by a black hole).

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you mean by "very strong".

The announced first detection (14th September 2015) was considered a very strong signal and that still only stretched the 4 km detector arms by less than the width of a proton (a tiny particle inside the nucleus of an atom). This wave would have no effect on a person.

You could hypothesis a stronger wave that would stretch and squish a person, I'm not sure what effect this would have but there are no objects in nature capable of producing waves this strong, even something as close as our sun becoming a supernova wouldn't be that strong, so it will never happen in real life.

Comment: I would think (but I'm not smart enough to do the math) that if you had a situation where the gravitational wave could be felt, then the tidal forces would uncomfortably large as well, but perhaps that would depend on the size of the black holes.